# Disable the Drop down column based on the text value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am working with SharePoint 2010 form library.

I have a drop down column which is dependent on text input column value .

The value in the Text input column comes from the infopath form.

**What i want is :-**

Suppose the text column value is "AU" then disable the Drop down column otherwise enable it.

I want to code this in Sharepoint Form library Edit page(Editpage.aspx).

I think it would be possible with Jquery.

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

--
Update:

This is the code which i am using in the Sharepoint Edit Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        if ($("#Test Value").val() != null) { 
            $("Select[Title='Test_Status']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
        } 
    }); 
</script>
```

But it's not working! In nutshell I want is when the text column(Test Value) value is blank then the Choice column(Test_Status) should be disabled and vice versa. For Refernence See the image below :
[image]

[image]

Comment: jQuery is a good solution. What is your question? Do you need help with the jQuery? Or help putting jQuery on the page? Please be specific and describe what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks 4 ur reply...!!
This is the code which i am using in the Sharepoint Edit Page:
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>           
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    
  if  ($("#Test Value").val() != null)
  {
 $("Select[Title='Test_Status']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    }         
  
     }); 

</script>
But' it's not working....!! I have tried so many times...!!
In nutshell I want is when the text column(Test Value) value is blank then the Choice column(Test_Status) should be disabled and vice versa...!!

Comment: Kishan. No need for all the double exclamation marks and punctuation ...!! ?? etc - it makes your text hard to read.

Comment: Ok Sure @Ryan. Thanks for the sugesstion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem:

Below is the source of the Javascript attach it with code.

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"

**write this all code in the javasrcipt tag**

$(document).ready(function() {

```
// add change handler
$("input[title='Test Value']").change(function() {
    MasterSelectChange();
});
// call the change function to set up form for first display:
MasterSelectChange();
```

});

function MasterSelectChange()

{

```
var thisVal =  $("input[title='Test Value']").val();

if(thisVal == "AU")
{
  $("select[title='Test_Status']").closest("tr").hide();

    }
else
{
      $("select[title='Test_Status']").show();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if ($("input[title='Test Value']").val()) { 
        $("select[title='Test_Status']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } 
    else { 
        $("select[title='Test_Status']").removeAttr('disabled'); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thank Again..!!
I have Tried this  but only the disbaled condition worked.
As i open the form, the Test_Status column was disabled.It is not enabled in vice versa case..!!

Comment: for your reference i have added an image ...!! Please have a look on it...!!

Comment: Try my updated code. val() should return an empty string instead of null. And, really, the condition is unnecessary so you can take it out altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rich Bennema...!!
I have tried the updated code as per your suggestion but it doesn't work ..!! 
Can you suggest any other approach to this ?